# C# Como Testart CommandsHandlers usando padrao Mediator e CQRS

Tags: c#, ddd, tdd, cqrs

Eu nunca trabalhei com tests antes e gostaria de aprender.

Estou usando os padroes MVC + DDD + Domain Notifications + CQRS + Event  Sourcing + Unity of Work e Repository.

Ai esta meu controller

```
public class DepartmentsController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IDepartmentAppService _departmentAppService;


        public DepartmentsController(IDepartmentAppService departmentAppService,
            INotificationHandler<DomainNotification> notifications) : base(notifications)
        {
            _departmentAppService = departmentAppService;
        }

        public ActionResult Create(DepartmentViewModel departmentViewModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(departmentViewModel);
            _departmentAppService.CreateDepartment(departmentViewModel);

            if (IsValidOperation())
            {
                this.AddToastMessage("Success", "Department Saved", ToastType.Success);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            this.AddToastMessage("Error", GetNotifications().FirstOrDefault()?.Value, ToastType.Error);
            return View(departmentViewModel);
        }
    }
```

E Meu Service Layer

```
 private readonly IMediatorHandler _bus;
    private readonly IDepartmentRepository _departmentRepository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;


    public DepartmentAppService(IMapper mapper,
        IDepartmentRepository departmentRepository,
        IMediatorHandler bus)
    {
        _departmentRepository = departmentRepository;
        _bus = bus;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }



     public void CreateDepartment(DepartmentViewModel departmentViewModel)
    {
        var registerCommand = _mapper.Map<RegisterDepartmentCommand>(departmentViewModel);
        _bus.SendCommand(registerCommand);
    }
```

Eu não tinha ideia de onde eu deveria começar a criar meus projetos de testes, então eu comecei na minha camada de aplicação e criei um método para testar meus comandos, começando pelo Create. Então eu escrevi isso.

Mas, como disse eu disse que não tenho idéia do que estou fazendo, gostaria de saber Se estou no caminho certo ou devo fazer outra coisa ...

```
[TestClass()]
public class DepartmentAppServiceTests
{

    private readonly Mock<IMediatorHandler> _mediatorHandlerMock;
    private readonly Mock<IDepartmentRepository> _departmentRepositoryMock;
    private readonly Mock<IMapper> _mapper;

    public DepartmentAppServiceTests()
    {
        _mediatorHandlerMock = new Mock<IMediatorHandler>();
        _departmentRepositoryMock = new Mock<IDepartmentRepository>();
        _mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();

    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void CreateDepartmentTest()
    {
        //Arrange
        var fakeDepartment = GetFakeDeparment();
        var fakeDepartmentVm = new DepartmentViewModel();

        Mock<RegisterDepartmentCommand> expected = new Mock<RegisterDepartmentCommand>();
        expected.SetupGet(x => x.Id).Returns(new Guid());
        expected.SetupGet(x => x.Name).Returns("Department Test");

        _departmentRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetById(It.IsAny<Guid>()))
            .Returns(fakeDepartment);

        _mediatorHandlerMock.Setup(x => x.SendCommand(It.IsAny<RegisterDepartmentCommand>()));

        //Act
        var departmentService = new DepartmentAppService(
            _mapper.Object,
            _departmentRepositoryMock.Object,
            _mediatorHandlerMock.Object);


        _mapper.Setup(m => m.Map<Department, DepartmentViewModel>(It.IsAny<Department>())).Returns(fakeDepartmentVm);

        departmentService.CreateDepartment(fakeDepartmentVm);

        //Assert
      //  !_notifications.HasNotifications();



    }

    private Department GetFakeDeparment()
    {
        return new Department()
        {
            Id = new Guid(),
            Name = "fakeName",

        };
    }
}
```

}

Comment: uma dica: tente expressar no método de teste o seguinte: o que está testando, qual o arrange e qual o resultado esperado, por exempo: "Departament_CriarDeptoValido_MapearResultadoCorreto"

Comment: A valeu, eu so nao botei o nome ainda pq realmente nao sei o que devo testar aqui!